# NSDate get local time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I build app that get date string(date in french time) from a database. after i get the string i convert it to nsdate:

```
NSString *dateStr = "20/3/2016 21:00 +0000";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm zzz"];
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
self.date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
```

Into `self.date` i get(if i print the object) :

```
2016-06-10 21:00:00 +0000
```

But when i try to convert it to local time:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSString *time = [formatter stringFromDate:cellItem.date];
```

I get a different time: `00:00`

Any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: did you try with other times ? I think I remember some strange conversions of time zones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default time zone for an `NSDateFormatter` is the time zone of the device, and as you didn't set it explicitly in the second formatter, that is what will be used.

Use the first formatter for both jobs or set it explicitly as you did in the first formatter:

```
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
```

Also a note on:

> Into `self.date` i get (if i print the object)

If you are using `NSLog()` or the debugger to view an `NSDate` object, it will use `[NSDate description]` to generate the string, which will always use the GMT time zone.  This constantly trips people up.